# Program crashes if using JS_NewGlobalObject : SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, c++, mozilla, spidermonkey

I am using the latest release of SpiderMonkey (js185-1.0.0.tar.gz) and when I am running the sample program which embeds Javascript, crashes the program

The sample program is directly from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine)

The program runs fine if I am using [JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject)
but the docs mention to use [JS_NewGlobalObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_NewGlobalObject) as it is "Obsolete since JSAPI 16"

Hence I replaced the `JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject` with `JS_NewGlobalObject` and since then the sample program crashes at line: 55 in the [sample program found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine)

What is the solution here?

I am using CentOS 6.2 64-bit version.

Comment: The program sample you cite is dated February 2000. The program may contain several obsolete functions, not just `JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject`. I would source another sample program from a more recent spidermonkey document.

Comment: @damienh: Compartments were introduced around Firefox 4 - quite definitely after February 2000 ;). February 2000 was the modification date of the document imported into MDN (this import happened in April 2006 according to the document history), it got quite a few changes since then however - most recent one in June this year. Still, this document refers to the JSAPI User Guide for better examples.

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation is likely related to the [recent change](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650353) to how compartments are created in SM (now every new global will get its own compartment by default).

You should be using JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject, as that function was only deprecated in JSAPI 16, 72 weeks after JS 1.8.5 was released :)